How to prove that two explicit functions are inverses of each other, using a computer algebra system.
Consider the following construction, of a two twisted strip:
$$r = 1 \text{ (radius)}.$$
$$w = 0.5 \text{ (width)}.$$
$$C(t) = r \begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\pi t) \\ \sin(2\pi t) \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Now at each point on the circle, $C(t)$, we want to add a vector on another circle spanned by the vectors $s C(t)$ and $s \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ where $s \in [0, w/2]$. These two vectors span a circle, and we use them to define a rod. If the main circle makes a full rotation, we want 2 half-twists of the second circle. The circular interpolation is given by:
$$
R(t, s) = s \cos(2\pi t) C(t) + s \sin(2\pi t) \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},
$$
Now a full parameterization of the $k$-twisted strip is:
$$
M(t, s) = C(t) + R(t,s)
$$
This would be an explicit parametrization of a Möbius strip with two twists. I know that such a Möbius strip is homeomorphic to the annulus. I can also parametrize an annulus $A(t, s) = s(\cos(2 \pi t), \sin(2 \pi t), 0)$.
I also have the inverse maps and hence the composition maps:
$$
S = A \circ M^{-1}
$$
$$
S^{-1} = M \circ A^{-1}
$$
Now my question:
I have a parametrization of an annulus, and of this 2-twisted strip, both using a square $[0, w/2] \times [0,1]$ for the parametrization. I want to show that there exists a function from $M$ to the annulus $A$, such that it is continuous and its inverse is continuous, i.e., a homeomorphism. How can I do such a thing? I tried manually, SageMath, and Mathematica but the computation $(S \circ S^{-1} == x)$ either produces a very large expression, or does not terminate. Using just numbers, I can easily verify that my function is a bijection. Does anyone have an idea how to proceed?

I would just argue via the topological route, instead of showing an explcit homeomorphism. You already have that the annulus and the two-twisted strip are homeomorphic to a square with gluing one side. Then by transitvity the claim follows.
